# Matlab ??? Error using ==> mldivide Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab

**I have codes like these in Matlab**

```
...
Kx=cell(10,10,10);
Kx2=cell(ee_max)
bX=cell(10,10)
bX2=cell(ee_max)
...
Kx{ee,ii,jj}=(1/36*VX{ee})*(alphX{ee,x}*bX{ee,ii}*bX{ee,jj}+alphX{ee,y}*cX{ee,ii}*cX{ee,jj}+alphX{ee,z}*dX{ee,ii}*dX{ee,jj})+VX{ee}*1/20*betaX{1+delXX{ii,jj}};
bX{ee,ii}=VX{ee}*(1/4)*f{ee}
...
Kx2{ee}=Kx{ee,:};
bX2{ee}=bX{ee,:};
phi_next=cell(4,4);
...
phi_next{ee}=bX2{ee}/Kx2{ee}
....
```

**I got error at this line**

```
phi_next{ee}=bX2{ee}/Kx2{ee}
```

as

```
??? Error using ==> mldivide
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

so,what should I do?
regards

Comment: That depends on what you want to accomplish. We cannot read your mind. You get an error because, as the error message tells you, you are trying to divide two matrices with incompatible sizes. It is up to you to figure out what you need to do. Maybe you're looking for the element-wise division `./`? `/` is matrix division.

Answer (score 0):

Use **./** instead of **/**.
The code is not complete so you may have other errors with other matrices dimensions.
If you find other errors you may use **.*** instead of * also when you multiply matrices with different dimensions.

Example:
A: 3 rows, 4 columns
B: 2 rows, 4 columns
C: 4 rows, 1 column

You can use * to multiply A and C (3x4)(4x1) or B and C (2x4)(4x1).

However you need **.*** to multiply A and B (3x4)(2x1).

Comment: No, with `.*` you can’t multiply a 3x4 with a 2x1 matrix. They must have the same sizes. Or with very new versions of MATLAB you get implicit singleton expansion. But 3x4 and 2x1 will never match up.